# How could I use "display : flex " css property, on older versions of firefox and chrome?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, fallback

I have been trying to use "display: flex" which works on newer versions of browser but could not make it work on older versions. I tried to use the "display : box " property as a fallback but even it does not seem to work.

```
    #flexSampleDiv{
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-content: flex-start;
        align-items: stretch;
     }
```

And yes I am talking about multiline flex i.e, should be able to use  "flex-wrap : wrap" property which in above code block come at "flex-flow : row wrap".

Comment: can you paste some of your html or css?

Comment: In what browser did you try and what was the version ? CSS flexbox is supported only in IE >=10, FF >=31 and Chrome >=31 versions only. You can check the full set of supported versions here http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Yes It does work above firefox 27, and above chrome 31, but I wanted to know if there is some way it could work on older browsers, at least on firefox 18 or above.

Comment: I found out that "display : flex "  could be used in older browsers like FF18 but it is not able to render the "flex-wrap:wrap" property. Now I am searching for a fallback which can emulate "flex-wrap : wrap" in those browsers. Hope for a solution.

Comment: I don't think there's anything like "flex-wrap:wrap" in Firefox versions below 28. (That was added in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=939901 )  If you want to emulate it, you'll probably have to use a float-based layout instead of flexbox.  But I wouldn't recommend doing anything with Firefox versions that old, because (as with any old browser-versoin) they have publicly known security vulnerabilities (which have been fixed in newer versions).

Comment: Thank you @dholbert for your comment. I want to explain you the situation in a bit more detail. I with my team, am building web application to bring out interactive contents for kids of grade 7 till 10. Our products should also run on Browse activities of XO4 laptops (http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Browse) and XO1 laptops (http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Activities/Browse). The Browse activity is similar to firefox engine as they say. The problem is that I am not able to use "display: flex" on this browse activities. Also, we were not able to build latest version of firefox for these laptops.

Comment: @dholbert We use HTML5 , CSS3 and JS/Jquery to build our web applications. Hope we could get some help or useful information to sort the solution out. Thank you once again dholbert.

Comment: @roshanPoudyal Gotcha. I don't really have anything to suggest; basically, as you know, you can't rely on `display:flex` if you want to support browsers from before `display:flex` was implemented. You may have to fall back on a CSS-float-based layout, or HTML tables, or some sort of absolutely positioned layout system where you compute the positions/sizes yourself in javascript. Other folks on StackOverflow may have better suggestions along those lines, but I can't offer more; I'm on the browser-implementing side of development, not on the coding-up-web-pages-using-legacy-layout-tools side.

Answer (score 0):

Learn only how to use current/new standard flexbox properties and let tool to do the job for you. I use [**AutoPrefixer**](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) tool.